# Trouble with authorization using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I'm running the following script to login to the captive portal at my college :

```
import requests

values = {'username':'cisco','password':'cisco'}
r = requests.post('http://10.163.0.1/login',data=values)
print(r.text)
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
<html>

<body>

  <center>
    If you are not redirected in a few seconds, click 'continue' below<br>
    <form name="redirect" action="https://muj.i-on.in/" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="mac" value="7C:76:35:F4:73:56">
      <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="10.163.5.38">
      <input type="hidden" name="username" value="cisco">
      <input type="hidden" name="link-login" value="http://10.163.0.1/login">
      <input type="hidden" name="link-orig" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="error" value="Could not locate user 
    profile from context for authorization: c">
      <input type="hidden" name="chap-id" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="chap-challenge" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="link-login-only" value="http://10.163.0.1/login">
      <input type="hidden" name="link-orig-esc" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="mac-esc" value="7C%3A76%3A35%3AF4%3A73%3A56">
      <input type="hidden" name="interface-name" value="B2_Hostel-163">
      <input type="submit" value="continue">
    </form>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      <!--
      document.redirect.submit();
      //-->
    </script>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

And due to the following error, I'm unable to log in:

```
<html>
<input type="hidden" name="error" value="Could not locate user 
        profile from context for authorization: c">

</html>
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: What sort of authentication does the website use?  HTTP Basic Auth, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I started comparing the packets that I was sending and the packet sent via logging in using Chrome (I analysed the packets using  Wireshark), & the packets that were being sent by chrome contained a little more stuff particularly:

```
key: "radius1-44115"
value: "12"
```

so in my code I also sent this like so:

```
import requests
values={'username':'cisco','password':'cisco','radius1-44115':'12'} 
try:
    r=requests.post('http://10.163.0.1/login',data=values)
    print('Connected')
except:
    print('Attempt to authencticate failed,Re-trying......')
    connect()
```

And voila it started working I've no idea why though. It would be nice if someone could explain to me why it is working now.